# .NET 5 core api with Angular front end cors issues

Tags: c#, .net, angular, cors, .net-5

So I have everything set up with an oracle db. The API runs fine and my angular app is able to send get requests to it just fine, but my post requests don't seem to work. I have some custom authorization middleware. Now I know that it isn't the AUTH since all my get requests run fine.

The error is as follows:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44342/api/User/insertUser' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is an example of a post in one of my angular services

```
insertUser(model: Users_Viewmodel) {
  console.log(model);
  return this.http.post<Users_Viewmodel>(
    `${this.apiUrl}/api/User/insertUser`, model
  );
}
```

Now on my API side I have CORS set up in my Startup.cs:

```
// outside of my ConfigureServices method
readonly string MyAllowOrigins = "_myAllowOrigins";


//  in my ConfigureServices method
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

// In my Configure method
app.UseCors(MyAllowOrigins);
```

Lastly I have this in my API controller "UserController"

```
[HttpPost("insertUser")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult InsertUser([FromBody] Users_Viewmodel model)
{
    try
    {
        UserRepo.InsertUser(model);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Edit: Added all StartUp.cs code on request

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyApp.Api.Helpers;
using MyApp.Api.MiddleWare;
using MyApp.WebSocketHub;

namespace MyApp.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        readonly string MyAllowOrigins = "_myAllowOrigins";

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add session-related configuration at the beginning of the method
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Add this line

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "SessionVars";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<SessionManager>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowOrigins,
                        policy =>
                        {
                            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowCredentials()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
                        });
            });

            services.AddSignalR()
                .AddJsonProtocol(options => {
                    options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                });

            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = new AllUppercaseNamingPolicy();
                });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyApp.Api", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyApp.Api v1"));
            }

            app.UseCors(MyAllowOrigins);

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseSession();
            
            app.UseMiddleware<OpcAuthorizeMiddleware>();

            SessionManager.Initialize(httpContextAccessor);
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<WebSocketHub.WebSocketHub>("/ws");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: include the full startup.cs code... I believe the order of the app.UseCors call is important.

Comment: @pcalkins I have added the startUp.cs code

Comment: You appear to be mixing `http://` and `https://` - you should be using `https://` for _everything_.

Comment: @Dai In order to have them the same, I had them on both http. I still get the same error: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: "UseCors must be placed after UseRouting and before UseAuthorization"... try with that order.

Comment: also be sure https for both ends... browser will treat http/https as different domains, and will not allow credentials to be sent unless secure.

Comment: @pcalkins I have them set up as https now using mkcert to generate the certs for angular. I still seem to be having the same issue with it though. The app.UseCors is now placed between UseRouting and UseAuthorization as well and still it gives the same issue

Comment: yeah, setting up CORS for ASP.NET seems to be a bit of a pain... I ended up using a browser profile with web security turned off for debugging (CORS rules turned off).  Live published site stays same-site, without CORS headers as it should.

Comment: I think app.UseCors should also be before before "app.UseHttpsRedirection(); app.UseStaticFiles();" to try order of UseRouting, UseCors, UseHttpsRedirection, UseStaticFiles, UseAuthorization.... if this doesn't help, you need to check IIS for Options verb: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis#http-verbs… and/or install CORS module: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Comment: In my context I am using IIS Express in vs 2019 to get the backend API up and running so this knocks out installing the CORS module and checking IIS for Options verb... Unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[EnableCors("_myAllowOrigins")]` at the start of your controller.

```
[EnableCors("_myAllowOrigins")]
[HttpPost("insertUser")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult InsertUser([FromBody] Users_Viewmodel model)
{
    try
    {
        UserRepo.InsertUser(model);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with this and both as http I still got this error: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Can you share the API request header

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, my request headers I believe are just `accept: */*` and `Content-Type: application/json`. The curl response in swagger showed this `curl -X POST "https://localhost:44306/api/User/insertUser" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d` ... Along with some of the model json data I am passing...